# visual studio code remote integrated terminal not showing zsh theme

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I use **Remote SSH** extension (from a Windows PC) to connect to a **remote Linux Redhat host** where all my development work happens. I use zsh as the default shell in VS code integrated terminal.
Here is the content of my .zshrc file:

```
export ZSH="/home/myname/.oh-my-zsh"
ln -s /home/myname/tools/dracula-theme-master $ZSH/themes/dracula.zsh-theme
SAVEHIST=10
HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history
ZSH_THEME="dracula"
source /home/myname/tools/zsh-syntax-highlighting-master/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
```

I manually downloaded all the themes. Here is what I have under $ZSH/themes/:
[image]

And I have this line in my VS code settings.json:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/zsh"
```

When I exectue

```
echo $TERM:
```

[image]

Everything seems to be set correctly. But the theme does not seem to display properly showing below:
[image]

But I am expecting something like this (e.g., showing current git branch, richer syntax highlighting):
[image]

Is it because VS code integrated terminal dose not support displaying the themes?

Comment: Please show us `echo $TERM`

Comment: @DenisSheremet added the output: xterm-256color

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: @MosheGottlieb No, it is not a programming question. Forgive me if I posted this question in the wrong place. I will make the change if it is the case.